# Downloading file from "javascript:__doPostBack" link using Python

Tags: javascript, python, python-2.7

I have an existing Python script that was written using urllib2 to download from a http:// link:

```
import urllib2
import os.path
import os
from os import chdir, getcwd, listdir, path

print "downloading with urllib2"

f = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.dcregs.dc.gov/Notice/DownLoad.aspx?VersionID=4613531')
data = f.read()

with open( "11-B300.doc", "wb" ) as code :
code.write( data )

print "All done downloads!"
```

The source web-page has been reformatted to uses a "javascript:__doPostBack" address:

```
javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MainContent$rpt_ruleList$ctl02$Label1','')
```

My presumption is that there is some form of package, similar to urllib2, that will allow me to download the same information via the "javascript:__doPostBack" formatted address or to call the http url, where the information is located, from which I can then download the information.

The existing script was working well for my purposes, so I would like to limit the additional coding, if possible.

Is there an alternate to urllib2 that will allow me to do download the information in a similar manner?

Or am I going to have to get more sophisticated in my solution (e.g., using Selenium to scrape the information)? (Do I want to get more sophisticated so that I don't have to manage updates to individual urls?)

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Or you could just try to understand what `__doPostBack` does call. At a certain point it's almost sure to make a normal http request that you can reproduce with urllib2 and be done with it.

Answer (score 0):

This relates to the site that you're on using is using .NET WebForms which manages the state of the page & the interaction within hidden form variables.

So in short, you'll need to click the link via something like Selenium as you say